# Solr query that contains slash

Tags: search, solr

I've found an interesting query for Solr and it returns search results, but I don't understand, what is the purpose of slash symbol between the words?

```
duties:health/nurse
```

Anybody knows? Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. You can look at the analyzer chain to understand what happens.
My guess is that the analyzer chain turns the / into a space - which makes the query into

```
duties: health nurse
```

To find out your analyzer chain from the configuration - start by checking the type of the field

For example

```
   <field name="health" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

Now we look for the definition of the type

```
     <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

As you can see, we have an index analyzer and a query analyzer.

My query analyzer would turn / in the query into something else by using the StandardTokenizerFactory.

From the solr wiki:

**solr.StandardTokenizerFactory**

A good general purpose tokenizer that strips many extraneous characters and sets token types to meaningful values. Token types are only useful for subsequent token filters that are type-aware of the same token types. There aren't any filters that use StandardTokenizer's types.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that health/nurse is being viewed as a string literal as there are no spaces between.  Health / nurse should yield different results than health/nurse, correct?  If so, then health/nurse must be an indexed term in your documents.